# Mac `zsh: command not found: psql`

Tags: bash, macos, psql

I already added the path to the `.bash_profile` like this.

```
#psql
export "PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/14/bin:$PATH"
```

And I successfully ran `psql` after I do `source .bash_profile`.

The problem is that when I closed the terminal and reopen it, `psql` doesn't work. I have to `source .bash_profile` again. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are editing `.bash_profile` and using `zsh`  as your shell.

If you are to fix the problem, please edit `.zshrc`. Or alternatively, you can edit `.zprofile` and it will also work.

Comment: Editing `.zshrc` works, but editing `.profile` doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: I am sorry, for `zsh` you can edit `.zprofile` or you can  simply do this; `emulate sh -c '. ~/.profile'`. The above command make `.profile` editing work. You can refer to this post , https://superuser.com/a/187673

Answer (score 4):

Add the following command in your `~/.zshrc` by using `vim ~/.zshrc`

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@12/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@12/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@12/include"
```

Then close your terminal and write `psql postgres` again, If you get the same error like `zsh: command not found: psql` then try the blew process-

I hope `/Users/Library/PostgreSQL/12/bin is` not in your "path". So an easy solution would be to create a symbolic link for `psql` in `/usr/local/bin/`:

```
sudo ln -s /Users/Library/PostgreSQL/12/bin/psql /usr/local/bin/psql
```

Now restart your terminal(*close your terminal and open it*) & write `psql postgres` and see the result :)

[image]